# Is it possible to use OutputCache on mvc JsonResult controller methods?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, outputcache

I am trying to do this, and it leads to result with contentlen 0

It looks like:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 36000)]
public JsonResult GetFileClasses() 
{
   return this.Json(TopicConfig.FileExtensionsSettings.List)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: And yes, without OutputCache everything works great

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `OutputCacheAttribute` you must also specify , `VaryByParam` parameter. Otherwise you'll get this exception on result processing `System.Web.HttpException: The directive or the configuration settings profile must specify the 'varyByParam' attribute.` 
You can try to add this parameter and see if it works.

Comment: To clarify: `[OutputCache(Duration=36000, VaryByParam="")]`.  Thank you Branislav, this has been driving me nuts as well!!!